# Spring apllication run failed

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

Hey I'm getting this error and i cant solve it, thank you for your help

ERROR 7924 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource

here is my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>employeemanager</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>employeemanager</name>
    <description>Employee Manager App </description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and my application.properties:

```
# mySQL configuration
spring.datasource.url=jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanager
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=letmein 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Could you please post the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: [the stack trace of the exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOD4E.png)

Comment: Please, edit your question and post the stacktrace as formatted text

Answer (score 0):

On Spring Boot 2.5.X data.sql scripts are now run before Hibernate is initialized. If you want to use data.sql to populate a schema created by Hibernate try adding the following to your application.properties `spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization=true`.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration'  it gives me this error any idea?

Comment: Try adding the following to your application.properties: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

Answer (score 0):

```
# mySQL configuration
spring.datasource.url=jbdc:mysql://localhost:3306/employeemanager
```

there's a typo, its supposed to be **jdbc** not jbdc

Answer (score 0):

**As I do remember, I was facing similar issue during integration.**

Could you please validate your pom.xml and application.properties/application.yaml configurations as below.

**Sample - Maven Pom.xml**


4.0.0

```
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Application Properties** - application.yaml

```
spring:
 datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bootdb
  username: root
  password: admin
 jpa: 
  hibernate.ddl-auto: update
  show-sql: true
 user.datasource.driver-class-name: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

**For more detail you may go through following working examples:**

1. https://thebasictechinfo.com/interview-preparation/spring-boot-oauth2-securing-rest-api/
2. https://thebasictechinfo.com/java-8/spring-boot-spring-security-with-database-authentication-mysql-rest-api-example/

**Also, could you try with following properties.**

```
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl=jdbc:mysql://localhost/bootdb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=admin
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Enjoy :)